# What is the cube equivalent to the given equation describing square?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

The equation

$$
|x+y|+|x-y|=L
$$

describes the boundary of a square in 2D. I am looking for the equivalent equation describing the surface of a cube in 3D. Something of the form
$$
|???| + |???| + |???| = L
$$

or similar.

I am aware of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639722/is-there-a-real-continuous-function-of-a-cube), but the given equation is not in the form I am looking for (EDIT: Meaning it uses max()).

Comment: What do you mean? What are $x$ and $y$ supposed to represent?  The perimeter of a square is $4$ times the length of one side.  The surface area of a cube is $6$ times the square of the length of an edge.

Comment: @RobertIsrael The set of points $(x,y)$ in the Cartesian plane satisfying their first equation is the boundary of a square. They are asking if there is an equation with $x,y,z$, in the form of a sum of absolute values equalling a constant, whose solution set is the boundary of a cube.

Comment: I changed the question to say boundary. English is not my first language,sry.

Comment: To get rid of the $\max$, use the two identities: $\max(a,b,c) = \max(a,\max(b,c))$ and $\max(a,b) = \frac12 ((a+b) + |a-b|)$.

Comment: @achillehui Ah, that helps a lot. Thank you.

Comment: @Garbaz Just so you know, perimeter can both refer to the boundary, and the length of the boundary, so your phrasing was correct. When they say "secure the perimeter," they are not talking about securing a numerical quantity!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use 
$$ |x| + |y| + \big||x| - |y|\big| + 2 |z| + \Big||x| + |y| + \big| |x| - |y| \big| - 2 |z| \Big| = 2 L $$

This comes from using $2 \max(a,b) = a+b + |a-b|$ twice on $L/2 = \max(|x|,|y|,|z|) = \max(\max(|x|,|y|),|z|)$.

Comment: Thank you. Surprising that the equation looks so asymmetrical (z being used very differently than x and y).